# hasn't have vs. didn't: which one is correct?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

What is correct and what is the difference between:

> - I didn't see anybody there.

> - I haven't seen anybody there.

Comment: A full list of possible contexts and meanings probably wouldn't fit in a comment. Maybe someone else will write it all out as an Answer

Comment: I've voted to close.  There is no special meaning or difference,  just the usual past tense/present perfect tense.  What does your grammar book say about these two common tenses?  Why do you suppose one is not correct?  More details, please!

Comment: @JamesK: One difference is that the ***didn't*** version strongly implies *...when I was there **on a single** (contextually relevant) **occasion*** (recently), whereas the ***haven't*** version strongly implies ***...ever*** (i.e. - *I've been there many times, but have **never** seen anyone there*).

Answer (score 2):

> I didn't see anybody there.

This is a completed action.
At some time in the past you were "there" and during that time you didn't see anybody.

> I haven't seen anybody there.

This would be okay for "*I haven't seen anybody **here***", referring to the period of time that you have been where you are now.

It would be inappropriate for a single occurrence at some other location though.

But it would be okay if you "*haven't seen anybody there*" in any of the many times that you had been there.